# Merging codeaurora prima wlan

Tags: git-merge

I'm trying to merge wlan prima codeaurora in https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/vendor/qcom-opensource/wlan/prima/
And its successfully.

I just want to ask: what is benefit merging prima wlan from aurora?
Is it a must?

Answer (score 0):

> what is benefit merging prima wlan from aurora?

You can see an illustration of that benefit in [supercairos/android_device_xiaomi_land issue 1](https://github.com/supercairos/android_device_xiaomi_land/issues/1): for WLAN, adding the prima module to your Android kernel.

Using that project means using one of the [msm-wlan projects](https://www.codeaurora.org/project/msm-wlan): a collection point for open source downloads, patches, and other materials specifically associated with the integrated WLAN solution found on selected Qualcomm MSM devices.